# PHP code not being invoked from Android

Tags: java, php, android, browser

I am trying to invoke the PHP code on the server to insert a record into the SQL data base. PHP Service "http://79.170.40.181/ramesh.com/serviceaddAndroid.php/" works fine when I invoke it from a web browser.

```
<?php
//$dir = 'sqlite:/Users/lakshmi/Documents/ServiceTesting.sqlite';
$dir = 'sqlite:./AndroidDatabase.sqlite';
$dbh  = new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database");

echo ">>> Enter script :\n";
// Read request parameters
$fname = $_REQUEST["Fname"];
$lname = $_REQUEST["Lname"];
$msisdn = $_REQUEST["Msisdn"];

echo ">>> MSISDN :"; echo $msisdn; echo "\n";
echo ">>> Fname :"; echo $fname; echo "\n";
echo ">>> Lname :"; echo $lname; echo "\n";


echo ">>> Before  Insert :\n";
$dbh->exec( "INSERT INTO TestWithAndroid (Fname, Lname, Msisdn ) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$msisdn')");

echo ">>> After  Insert :\n";

?>
```

The debug lines in the java code are as follows:

```
I/System.out: ====conn=  com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://79.170.40.181/ramesh.com/serviceaddAndroid.php
I/System.out: ======Connection DOne ====
I/System.out: ======Connection DOne ====Fname=Masoor&Lname=Ramesh&Msisdn=5555555555
I/System.out: ======Reader.readLine() ====>>> Enter script :
I/System.out: ======Reader.readLine() ====>>> MSISDN :
I/System.out: ======after getOutSteam write  ====
I/Add: Done
I/IP in main  =: Done
```

I am calling this from the Async task. I am using the same string to call the PHP service, but it neither inserts not gives an error message.

```
private String addToDb() {

        String urlParameters  = "Fname="+"Masoor"+"&"+"Lname="+"Ramesh"+"&"+"Msisdn="+"5555555555";


        byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int    postDataLength = postData.length;
        //String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
        //let myUrl = URL(string: "http://localhost:8000/serviceadd-all-good.php/")
        //String request = "http://79.170.40.181/ramesh.com/serviceaddAndroid.php";
        String request = "http://79.170.40.181/ramesh.com/serviceaddAndroid.php";
        URL url=null;

        try {
             url = new URL(request);
            //HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("====conn=  "+conn.toString());
            conn.setDoOutput( true );

           // conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
            //conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
            //conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            //conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
            //conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
           // conn.setUseCaches( false );

            System.out.println("======Connection DOne ====");
            OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("======Connection DOne ===="+urlParameters);
            writer.write(urlParameters);
            writer.flush();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line1 = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("======Reader.readLine() ===="+line1);
            String line2 = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println("======Reader.readLine() ===="+line2);
            /*
            try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
                System.out.println("======before wr rite  ====");
                wr.write(postData);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

                System.out.println("======after wr  write  ====");
            } catch (IOException m) {

                System.out.println("Error after write to output stream:" + m);
            }
            //conn.getOutputStream().write(postData);
            */

            System.out.println("======after  write & read ====");
            } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Err :"+e);

            Log.i("Add","Error");
            return("Error");
        }
```

I do not get any error or exception and  the record is not inserted.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Let your php script echo more data. At the moment you do not know what happens. Start with just echoing all parameters with their vslues. Echo what the script is doing.

Comment: At the moment your android code does not read the echo() from the php script. Start adding that code so you know what is echoed. As only then you will know what happens.

Comment: I am able to add a record to Sql DB when I run the script from browser. I have debug statements that show it connects to the URL but does not seem to run the script  also the echo statement invoked from the php java does not print. I am able to ping the site.

Comment: Well not to the point. If you want to debug this then do as i asked you to do. And show us what you do. Also debug statements.

Comment: Ok.. Here is the php script with more echo statements:

Comment: I have updated the script with a couple of echo statements.. I have also pasted the output of the Android monitor after launching the app.  Sorry it is a lot of stuff.  My debug statements from Java I have done in bold above.  Where should I see the output of echo statement I added in script?  Thanks

Comment: Do you really think we can read those logs? Can you? You should read the echos from the inputstream with readLine. Like you write the data to the output stream. Only then you see the echos.

Comment: `echo "Row inserted \n";`. You are blindly echoing that. You echo it allways. But your insert can fail.

Comment: Got it.  I did not know I could do a readLine to readh echos.  Thanks I learnt something new today.  So I updated the PHP script with a couple of debug statements.  I notice it does enter the script but is not able to extract the input parameters. And it is not executing the INSERT command.  It echos all statements up to echo $fname.. Am I not sending the parameters correctly?

Comment: Add the code where you read the echos. Do away with all database code in your php script and first care for receiving the parameters correct. Echo all parameters.

Comment: `/System.out: ======after getOutSteam write  ====`. Very strange that you have that log line AFTER you logged those readLines. First do all writing. Then the reading.

Comment: That statement is after write and read.. You help me a lot.  Now I know it is getting into script,, but is not able to read the parameters nor does it execute the INSERT command.   However when I run the PHP script from the web browser is does create an empty record when I do not pass any parameters

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help in debugging!  I was passing postData instead of urLParameters and it works now.  However, I was doing the same thing before but was not working . It is strange.. I have updated the code accordingly.